# How to apply Tailwind Typography custom color theme

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm [following the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin#adding-custom-color-themes) to build my custom color theme called "maincolors" for the Typography Tailwind plugin, this way:

```js
theme: {
  colors: {
    dark: '#1c1c1c',
    midup: '#565656',
    middle: '#969393',
    light: '#e3e3e3',
    white: '#ffffff',
    black: '#000000',
  },
  extend: {
    typography: ({theme}) => ({
      maincolors: {
        css: {
          '--tw-prose-headings': theme('colors.dark'),
        },
      },
   },
}
```

Now, how do I apply the "maincolors" theme to the front?

Answer (score 3):

I found it:

```
class="prose prose-maincolors"
```